# Pascal - Wrong number of parameters

Tags: mingw, pascal

Working on a record program and I'm a little stuck.

```
program myMusicPlayer;
uses TerminalUserInput, SysUtils;

type
genreType = (Comedy, Punk, Metal);


album = record
    albumName : String;
    artistName : String;
    genre : genreType;
    tracks : array [0..4] of String;
    location: array [0..4] of String;
end;

function readGenre(prompt: String): genreType;
var
val : Integer;

begin
WriteLn('1 - Comedy');
WriteLn('2 - Punk');
WriteLn('3 - Metal');
val := ReadInteger(prompt);

while ((val < 1) or (val > 3)) do
begin
    WriteLn('Please enter a value between 1 & 3');
    val := ReadInteger(prompt);
end;

result := genreType(val-1);
end;

function readAlbum(const alb : album): album;
var
i: Integer;

begin
result.albumName := ReadString('Enter album name here: ');
result.artistName := ReadString('Enter artist name here: ');
result.genre := readGenre('Enter genre here: ');

for i := 0 to 4 do
begin
    result.tracks[i] := ReadString('Enter track list here: ');
end;
for i := 0 to 4 do
begin
result.location[i] := ReadString('Enter file location here: ');
end;
end;

procedure printAlbum(const toPrint: album);
var
i : Integer;

begin
WriteLn('Album title: ', toPrint.albumName);
WriteLn('Artist name: ', toPrint.artistName);
WriteLn('Genre: ', toPrint.genre);

for i := 0 to 4 do
begin
    WriteLn('Track ', i, ' is: ', toPrint.tracks[i]);
    WriteLn('File ', i, ' location is: ', toPrint.location[i]);
end;
end;
```

Issue is happening with this procedure "runAlbum", Im trying to use this so users can select a number between 1 - 4 to select the corresponding track they entered before hand.

```
procedure runAlbum(prompt: String; min, max: Integer);
var
result : Integer;

begin
result := ReadInteger(prompt);
while ((result < min) or (result > max)) do
begin
    WriteLn('Please select a track between', min, ' and ', max, ' to play: 
');
    result := ReadInteger(prompt);
end;
end;
```

However I am unclear exactly what parameters I need to enter in the brackets next to runAlbum to get the program to run, as of right now everything I've tried runs the error "Wrong number of parameters set for "runAlbum"".

```
procedure Main();
var
newAlbum : album;

begin
newAlbum := readAlbum(newAlbum);
printAlbum(newAlbum);
runAlbum(); 
end;

begin
Main();
end.
```

Answer (score 4):

When you call `runAlbum`, you have to provide values (aka arguments) for each of the parameters specified in its declaration, i.e. `Prompt`, `min` and `max`.  At the moment, you are not proving any parameter values, because of the empty parentheses in your call.

So you should be calling it with something like

```
runAlbum(newAlbum.albumName +': enter a track number to play', 0, 99);
```

Of course, the values 0 and 99 should be replaced by the lowest and highest numbers available for `newAlbum`.  I assume you will be able to work out how to supply the relevant values from the album data.

Comment: That works, thanks! 
However I've realised that the user has to select a track number and then the terminal has to print "The track you selected", followed by the track name, "from the album:", followed by the album name, "is now playing!".
I dont know how to implement that, should I make a new function or can I add it to procedure runAlbum?

Comment: @ScottNeely:  Btw, if this answer helped, please feel free to accept it, by clicking the tick icon at its top left.